# initialise d3 quadtree with arbitrary x and y names

Tags: javascript, d3.js, quadtree

I want to set up a d3 quadtree using data which does not have columns labelled x and y, but with some other labels. Reading the quadtree docs I thought I could do it like this:

```
var data = [{"a":6,"b":99.0},{"a":12,"b":227.0},{"a":2,"b":43.0},{"a":23,"b":32.0}];

var xname = "a";
var yname = "b";

var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(data)
.x(function(d) {return d[xname]; })
.y(function(d) {return d[yname]; });
```

But when I run this code I get an error:

```
TypeError: d3.geom.quadtree(data).x is not a function. (In 'd3.geom.quadtree(data).x(function(d) {return d[xname]; })', 'd3.geom.quadtree(data).x' is undefined)
```

How can I set up the quadtree to use different x and y labels? (Obviously I could change the data to use "x" and "y" but there are reasons I don't want to do that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create your quadtree passing it data

e.g :

```
var data = [{"a":6,"b":99.0},{"a":12,"b":227.0},{"a":2,"b":43.0},{"a":23,"b":32.0}];

var xname = "a";
var yname = "b";


var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(/* nothing here */)
     .x(function(d) {return d[xname]; })
     .y(function(d) {return d[yname]; });
```

data binding must append later

```
d3.selectAll('circle').data(quadtree(data))
   .append('circle');
```